# How to check if you are clicking on a radio buttons that's already selected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have several rows of twin radio buttons that are generated via a loop in ruby on rails.  For each row, one of the button is already selected, how do i detect if the user accidentally click on a radio button that's already selected?  Keep in mind these buttons all have generated ids so I can just look for a specific id.  Can someone show me how to do this via ruby on rails or javascript?  Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to add some more detail.  What do you want to actually happen when they click on a selected radio button?  On the high level you will need to create an event listener on the button and have that listener do whatever it is that you want done when the button is clicked and it has the class selected.

Comment: You can add [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) handler to radio input.

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$("#my_radio_button").click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert("radio button is already checked !");
  }
});
```